# Xamarin Forms Button taking up whole screen despite relative AbsoluteLayout LayoutBounds settings

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin

I am attempting to add a button to an absolutelayout using relative LayoutBounds so that it doesn't take up the whole screen. However, the button is taking up the whole screen. My c# code is as follows:

```cs
Button temp = new Button()
{
     Text = "Test"
};
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(temp, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(.1, .1, .1, .1));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(temp, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
photoGrid.Children.Add(temp);
```

photoGrid is my AbsoluteLayout. I am following the tutorial here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout#proportional-positioning-and-sizing) and see no reason why the button would be taking up the entire screen instead of a small part of it (10% away from the left and 10% away from the top with dimensions taking up 10% of the screen in each direction).

The AbsoluteLayout also has an image inside it by the time that this button is added; the XAML code is as follows:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="PhotoGrid" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="False">
     <Image x:Name="PhotoImage" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Finally, the AbsoluteLayout itself is inside a 1 row, 1 column grid. This is because the content of the page changes as the user uses the app, and placing several views inside a grid like this allows me to change which of them is visible at a given time depending on what the app is doing.

Why might the button generated with the c# code above take up the entirety of the full page gridview, and how can I fix this?

Comment: try "None" instead of "All" for `LayoutFlags`

Comment: Unfortunately, this still results in the button taking up the whole screen

Comment: this works fine for me when I test it.  If you can post a [mcve] somewhere I'll take a quick look.  But I'd suggest doing a mockup in XAML with a couple of hardcoded buttons to get it work like you want, then translate that to your C# to create the button dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test with your code , it works fine both on android and iOS .

[image][image]

Comment: Which platform did you test on ? What is the version of Xamarin.Forms on your side ? If possible could you provide a basic, reproducible project here ?

Comment: I am testing this code on a Pixel 3a XL emulator running Android 11 using Xamarin   16.10.000.230, Xamarin Designer 16.10.0.115, Xamarin Templates 16.10.5, and Xamarin.Android SDK 11.3.0.1. Which versions are you using?

Comment: In creating the minimal reproducible example I discovered that the grid the AbsoluteLayout was in was called photoGrid and the AbsoluteLayout was called PhotoGrid, and I was adding the button to the former instead of the latter hence it taking up the whole screen. I guess this is a lesson in being sure to differentiate variable names haha

Comment: Good, glad to hear that .